# jQuery set input value dynamically?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 3 text input areas, within a single form, with a preformated value, like "blue", "red", "green", and I'm in need of loading these values dynamically from a INI file instead of having them pre-written, without reloading the page, and each time I click a link. I can't have that link submitting a form.

Comment: It sounds a bit like you're trying to use jQuery in place of a server-side language... is that correct? With a server-side language you'd just use it to read the INI file and write out the input values...

Answer (score 3):

**Loading Values Dynamically**

1. Read INI file using PHP/ASP/Ruby/Python etc etc
2. Output those values to 3 JS variables or an array
3. Get your jquery to read that variable and populate the input boxes. You can use `$('#someid').val(someVal);`

Or

You can use AJAX to grab the values after the pages have loaded. Not much point in that though.

**Make links not clickable**

```
$('a').click(function(){
   return false; //Link clicked but does nothing
})
```

Comment: @JohnP ::: You can simply use `preventDefault();` function instead of `return false;`.

Comment: PS:

No this is not what I need, I think I found the pipeline, please write me a snippet on how to pass a link "rel" value trough ajax onto a php file that gets the "rel" value as a POST var, performs calculations with it and then returns the output of that php file into another form?


The ideia is to:

1. click a link, get its "rel" value.
2. Send that value into a php file.
3. Return the contents of that php file back (they will be 3 text input fields)
4. Paste them onto a form on the page

Comment: @Joricam Since you're new here you might not know that asking for a complete solution without any good faith effort on your part is frowned upon. Please try it out yourself and ask a new question if you run into problem. @Jack `return false` also stops event bubbling

Comment: Ok Thanks, I'm trying it right now after some hours of sleep, I need the link to retun true, thats not the problem. Best Regards

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

$(function (){

$(body).html('<p>Balls of steel</p>');


     });

</script>
</head>


<body>

</body>
</html>


I'm not sure about the body selector, but I tried with proper selected divs and the .html(...) is not working, does nothing, why?

Comment: You have to understand, I can't do debugging for you. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/html

Comment: Also there's a `;` next to your JS include

Comment: It sounds a bit like you're trying to use JQuery where you need a server-side language. What relevance does the INI file have here?